# QGIS Sextante Python UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: qgis, saga, sextante

I have some issues with Quantum Gis 1.8. When I try to use shapes to grid (sextante-saga tool) I get the following error (comes up when I try to define the new grid file name):

Fehler bei der Ausführung von Python-Code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\gui\OutputSelectionPanel.py", line 94, in saveToFile
    settings.setValue("/SextanteQGIS/LastOutputPath", os.path.dirname(str(filename)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

Python-Version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS-Version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, f440b60

Python-Pfad: ['C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante_taudem', 'C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins\sextantelwgeomprovider', 'C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins\sextanteexampleprovider', 'C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante', 'C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins\permaclim', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/Max/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools', 'C:/Tempordner_GIS/J\xc3\xbchnde']

Comment: Seems that the name of the file or path is the issue. Try again using only Latin characters in file names and paths.

Comment: Could be a character inside the .py file as well. I got similar error messages when having ä,ö,ü in my .py-files, even if it was out-commented.

Answer (score 2):

These problems are well known for QGIS 1.8. It looks like Sextante bug. Try newer versions.

Comment: @PolyGeo It may be wrong, and it may be unsupported, but it looks like an answer to me.  Msbilgin, could you provide some references for your assertion of being "well known"? That would help readers understand your answer and see to what extent it addresses the question.

Comment: I used QGIS 1.8 with Sextante in alot of projects. And those days i was stucked in analysis stages. Errors are same in these question. And i reported the bugs to http://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues?set_filter=1&tracker_id=1 ... People accepted these kind of errors in "well known" and said they'll remove these kind of error in new version... Check out the comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57606/sextane-script-error-os-is-not-defined